# How to Download Symfony library other than GitHub Website

Tags: symfony, github

Is there any way to download Symfony outside Git hub ?
the reason is that company security Blocked GitHub website.

Thank you for your support

Comment: Do you mean Symphony CMS (PHP) or the Symfony PHP framework?

Comment: symphony php framework

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is ambiguous. Is it spelt with 'ph' or 'f'? Please edit your question and tag with the correct spelling if necessary so that useful answers can be given.

Comment: sorry for the wron written word , yes you are right indeed it is symfony

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding and precision lacking . I am used to build everyhting using asp.net c# environment. and suddenly company decided to move through a whole other environment

Comment: since your company just changed everything, I don't think it is unreasonable to change blocked sites too; if you will be working with symfony and php, github is a must have